# Apache-NiFi DetectDuplicate processor counter

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying using NiFi to aggregate *multiple* repeated events into *one*, based on few attributes of flow files with **DetectDuplicate** processor

[image]

Is there any possibility to count how many unique events duplicated during *Age Off Duration*(seconds) and write a number under each unique event in non-duplicate flow?

I'll be glad to any help. Thanks.